# Combining Matrice with an array In Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I tried to shuffle two matrices. And before shuffling I tried to concatenate them since it looked easier.
(Since you wanted examples)For ex first matrix is:

```
A = [[ 1.  2.  3.   4]
     [ 1.  5.  6.   7]
     [ 1.  8.  9.   9]
     [ 1.  2.  1.   7]
     [ 1.  5.  5.   6]
     [ 1.  2.   3.  2]
     [ 1.  1.  4.   6]]
```

And the second is:

```
B = [ 1.  2.  3. 4. 5.  6.  7.]
```

Then how can I shuffle them?By shuffling I want to do something like this: first element of A will change places with first element of B. And the output will be:

```
A = [[ 1.]
 [ 1.  5.  6.   7]
 [ 1.  8.  9.   9]
 [ 1.  2.  1.   7]
 [ 1.  5.  5.   6]
 [ 1.  2.   3.  2]
 [ 1.  1.  4.   6]]
B = [ 1.  2.  3.   4].  2.  3. 4. 5.  6.  7.]
```

Is it possible?
I hope the question is more understandable now, thanks for helping.

Comment: As the error message states, the matrices need to have matching dimensions. If you include your input data in your question that would help.

Comment: We don't know what you intend to produce.  Give a small concrete example, with the 2 arrays and the desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out,

```
c = np.column_stack((A, B))
np.random.shuffle(c)
BB = c[:, 4]
AA= c[:, 0:4]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to concatenate two matrixes with different dimensions since the result matrix would be ambiguous.

You can either pad the smaller matrix with the same datatype (usually floats or integers) to fit the size of the larger matrix

```py
>>> result = np.full(fill_value=0, shape=b.shape)
>>> offset = (0, 0) # you can even set an offset
>>> result[offset[0]:a.shape[0]+offset[0],offset[1]:a.shape[1]+offset[1]] = a
```

or slice the larger one to fit the size of the smaller one.

```py
>>> b[:a.shape[0],:a.shape[1]]
```

Since you ask such a general question it's hard to know what exactly the solution could be.